# How to know, how List view is sorted?

Tags: apex, force.com, list-view

I want to know the current state of a list view( how it is sorted).
Is there is any way we can know in apex how a particular list is currently sorted?

Suppose if a list view is sorted in ascending order of last name.Is there is anyway in apex we can know the same?

Comment: On default salesforce pages or visualforce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you can not (within reason) get this information. Salesforce does store this on a per user basis in the database.

If you would know you user's latest order preference, you can with apex query data with a specific ordering by using the `Order By` clause.

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,email FROM Contact ORDER BY lastname
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm

Comment: and its only List's that can be sorted, so if you have it in a Map or Set then the order is not guaranteed :-(